# How can you upload to CatBox using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, api, upload

I am making an app and wanted to add a client-side uploader. I found a couple of services, including:

[file.io](https://www.file.io/)

[catbox](https://catbox.moe/) (probably the one I want to use)

[Uguu](https://www.uguu.se/)

[put.re](https://put.re/api-docs)

They all support curl as seen from the documentation but as I said I want a preferably JavaScript solution for the client (I am kinda a newbie in JS), and if that is not possible maybe a PHP one?
Thanks in advance, Filip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var apiUrl = 'https://api.put.re/upload';

var settings = {
  async: false,
  crossDomain: true,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST',
  url: apiUrl,
  mimeType: 'multipart/form-data'
};

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("image", $files);
settings.data = formData;

$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
    var data = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(data)
```

[working demo](http://uni.hys.cz/file)
}